# Is it possible to bring native UI's into Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am  pretty new to cocos2d-x. Surfing internet did not help much.

**My Question:**

We have requirement to develop an application which has more controls like calender, table, options along with few animation stuff. I really impressed with cocos2d-x.  But i do not find any use cases like calender, table , that can be used in cocos2d-x, unless we write on our own. [ i may be wrong also here ].

So, Kindly suggest, if going with cocos2d-x , can i achieve the said above?.

Comment: If you want the UITableView etc then link to the UIKit framework and use them (with Objective-C code). There's no native GUI for cocos2d besides menu and perhaps you'll find slider or button controls on the net but most of them … well I'd still rather write them myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are some extensions inside cocos2d-x distibution (see ./extensions folder), and some UIKit classes reimplementations on github. Animations usually implemented with `CCAction` subclasses (like `CCMoveBy`, `CCMoveTo`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use native controls using a bridge between Cocos2d-x and Objective C
Here is an [example](http://www.plungeinteractive.com/blog/communication-between-c-and-objective-c-code/) of how to achieve it.

However these native UI will run only for iOS. You wont be able to get the benefit of cocos2d-x being multiplatform.